# Node.js module for retrieving image meta data (EXIF/IPTC) without dependencies

Tags: library, javascript, images, node.js, exif

I need node.js a library that extracts the following information from images:

- original date time (optionally also GPS time stamp)
- GPS longitude + latitude
- exposure time
- (optional) time zone + offset
- (optional) camera make + model

Other requirements:

- It should run on any of the three big platforms: Windows, Linux & Mac.
- It's preferable that it supports native compilation through node-gyp or something like that, but it can also be pure JavaScript which of course reduces the performance. It's also possible that it still depends on an external native library, but it should download and install the library in a fully automatic fashion in that case.
- It should be free (not necessarily open source).
- License: any.